# IntelliJ Not Working With Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been working in Eclipse for a while now, and I decided to check out **IntelliJ Idea 2017.1.5.** I've been having trouble getting the program to run. Maybe you can help me? `Error:C:\Users\christine\Downloads (Access is denied)` I get this error message. This is where I store my projects for Java. If any of you can help me please write a reply.

Comment: Try open intellij as adminisrtrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on InelliJ icon and choose run as administrator.  This will probably solve the issue.

If this didn't work you can also move your projects to another drive of your pc and set there as your workspace.

Comment: thanks for helping! I just had to install a jdk & run it as administrator  & create a folder called '**ideaProjects**' :P